# Defining function that takes arguments in prefix notation scala

Tags: scala

I want to do define a function in scala that takes arguments in prefix notation:

```
sum i1 i2 i3 ... in
```

and returns and Int with the sum of all the provided args. Note that I don't want to use parentheses when I call the function.

My goal is to do something like `sum i1 plus i2` but I want to start with something simpler first.

NOTE: You might say there is not purpose for doing this if you can use the + operator, but my goal is not to add numbers. I am just using this as a generic learning tool.

Comment: Would you accept `i1 plus i2 plus ...`? It's way simpler...

Comment: It would be nice to know how that is defined. Although I am more interested right now in the prefix notation call. If you can show how your example can be done it would be appreciated as well. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the question, I'd like to point out that scala is first and foremost an object oriented language, so most of the functions you'll want to define will actually be methods on specific objects. I will give answers in more generality for any class `T` (not necessarily for `Int`). I also assume that what you want to do on your list of values can be done iteratively, so `sum 1 2 3` is actually the same as `sum (sum 1 2) 3`, so I assume you have some reducer function `f: (T, T) => T`.

To define an infix operator, so that you can do something like

```
i1 and i2 and i3 ...
```

you just have to define a method

```
and(that: T): T = f(this, that)
```

on your class `T`. If you are not able to add methods to your type (eg, if you're using a class from a lib, or `Int`s), you can use an [implicit wrapper](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) for your type:

```
implicit class ReducibleT(i: T) {
  def and(j: T): f(i, j)
}
```

To define a prefix operator, with infix repeater, such as

```
sum i1 and i2 and i3 ...
```

it appears that you cannot do it! That's because an expression like `ident1 ident2 ident3` is always (as far as I know) parsed as `ident1.ident2(ident3)`, (unless `ident2` ends with a colon, in which case it is reversed). But you cannot define a method for all possible identifiers for your type `T` (eg, for `Int`s, you cannot define a method `1` on an object, so `sum 1 2` has no meaning whatsoever), so it won't be possible.

However, you can do almost as good:

```
sum (i1) and i2 and i3 ...
```

In that case, the parens indicates a function call, so it actually calls the method `and` on the object `sum(i1)` (which actually is `sum.apply(i1)`, since all functions are objects with the special method `apply`). Here is an example:

```
def sum(i: T) = i

implicit class ReducibleT(i: T) {
  def and(j: T): f(i, j)
}
```

Now, if you understood this second case, it will come to no surprise that you cannot do

```
sum i1 i2 i3 ...
```

either. We have to limit ourselves to

```
sum (i1) (i2) (i3)
```

using the following:

```
def sum(i: T) = i

implicit class ReducibleT(i: T) {
  def apply(j: T) = f(i, j)
}
```

Or, to mix things up a bit, you can use implicit conversion to a function:

```
implicit def tAsReducer(i: T): T => T = f(i, _)
```